# how to declare a type that extend a abstract class which has method return type include keyof this in typescript

Tags: typescript, abstract-class, keyof

```
abstract class AbstractCard {
  foo = 1
  getKeys(): Array<keyof this> {
    return ['foo']
  }
}

class Card extends AbstractCard {
  bar = 2
  getKeys(): Array<keyof this> {
    return [...super.getKeys(), 'bar']
  }
}

const logCard = (card: AbstractCard) => {
  console.log(card.getKeys())
}

const card = new Card()

logCard(card)
```

> TS2345: Argument of type 'Card' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AbstractCard'.   The types returned by 'getKeys()' are incompatible between these types.     Type '(keyof Card)[]' is not assignable to type '(keyof AbstractCard)[]'.       Type 'keyof Card' is not assignable to type 'keyof AbstractCard'.         Type '"bar"' is not assignable to type 'keyof AbstractCard'.

solved by using generic

```
abstract class AbstractCard {
  foo = 1
  getKeys(): Array<keyof this> {
    return ['foo']
  }
}

class Card extends AbstractCard {
  bar = 2
  getKeys(): Array<keyof this> {
    return [...super.getKeys(), 'bar']
  }
}

const logCard = <T extends AbstractCard>(card: T) => {
  console.log(card.getKeys())
}

const card = new Card()

logCard(card)
```

Comment: I wish this were phrased like a question instead of just a title and uncommented code.  There's an interesting story to tell here about polymorphic `this` and contravariance working together to break the relationship between sub*classes* and sub*types*.  But as it is I'm not sure what you're looking for exactly.  Could you flesh this out?

Comment: Note to self or others, this behavior is https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28476 and https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39375 and working as intended.

Comment: Just a workaround https://tsplay.dev/Na0a0w   . `const logCard = <A extends AbstractCard>(card: A) =>`